# How to play .avi video with android 2.2 sdk in java?

Tags: java, android

I'm very new to android jdk,

anyone knows how to play `.avi` in it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use [MediaPlayer](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.html). See the example [here](http://www.androidpeople.com/android-mediaplayer-example/).

Comment: Do you know how to play flash BTW?

Comment: nope, haven't worked with flash.

Comment: You are also going to want to make sure your video codec matches the ones supported by Android AND your particular device: http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/media-formats.html